# Sandy bridge + 12.10: tricks

Tags: 12.10, boot, kernel, intel

Are there any *tricks* (like boot parameter or unofficial kernel or anything), which would improve Ubuntu 12.10 on sandy bridge with Intel HD 3000? It is not totally bad now, but maybe there is something to do to make notebook cooler and quieter?

Comment: Improve in what way?

Comment: It isn't really hot or really noisy but it is still a bit noisier and hotter than Windows (or even than OS X on my notebook :>) I wonder, if there are any tricks (that for example aren't turned on by default because they can be a bit unstable) to make notebook a bit cooler.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your kernel version, try adding `i915.lvds_downclock=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.powersave=1 i915.semaphores=1 pcie_aspm=force` in your `grub.cfg`, so it looks similar to:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.0-11.dmz.1-liquorix-amd64 root=UUID=dd4d6a9c-b942-4137-97ed-ccd2ddc15530 ro  quiet i915.lvds_downclock=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1 i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.powersave=1 i915.semaphores=1 pcie_aspm=force
```

I'm on Debian, so maybe looks different in Ubuntu. Also some kernel-versions run hotter, like kernel 3.7 runs 10°C hotter for me (I heard in upcoming kernel 3.8 above options aren't needed).

If there's a seperate Nvidia graphics card, checkout Bumblebee for turning it off, which also should help on temps and noise.

Comment: I suppose you mean "add ... to the kernel command line", not "add to grub.cfg". This is in no way specific to grub, or to any distro. These are linux configuration parameters, they work as far as it's linux (the kernel).